# What is the one form given its value for a vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

I read an article on vector fields. the author defined a 1-form on a manifold $M$ as $u(X)=\rho$ when $X$ is a given vector field and $\rho$ is a given real valued function defined on $M$. can we deduce the values of $u(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}), i=1,n$. I got the following equation
\begin{equation}
\Sigma \ X^{i} u_{i}=\rho \ , \ u_{i}= u(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}})
\end{equation}
It is only one equation in $n$ unknown functions. If I was right is there is a way to get a general form of these function?
When we solve a linear equation in two unknowns we get finitely many solutions and we represent them using a parameter. Can any one give an idea to solve like this one?
The author says that there is a vector field $U$ associated with this form such that $g(U,X)=u(X)$. Can anyone deduce this vector field.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless $M$ is one-dimensional this is not enough information - consider the case $X = \partial/\partial x^1$. Perhaps the author just needs any 1-form satisfying this condition rather than a unique one?

Comment: Thank you. Is there a general form of all forms that satisfies this condition. Again thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

*Solution:*

The expression
$$u(X)=g(U,X)$$ 
would be an example of the **Riesz's representation theorem**, the vector $U$ represents the 1-form $u$ in this sense.

By the use of local coordinates we have $U=u^s\partial_s$ and (employing *Eisntein's sum convention*)  then 
$$u=u_sdx^s,$$ 
where the relations 
$$u_k=g_{kt}u^t,$$
are involved. Here $g_{ij}=g(\partial_i, \partial_j)$.

Comment: I google this theorem, I found a theorem in Hilbert space!. I just want to describe $U$ using the I-form $u$. Thank you

Comment: are you wonted with the sum convention?